# Create bins from an object

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset, data-science

I have the following series object type

print(df['MySpecificBins'])

| Column A |
| --- |
| 25- 34 |
| 19-24 |
| 55-64 |

I can't use this function because my data is not continuous

```
bins = [-np.inf, 19, 24, 25,34,35,45,54,55,64,65 ,np.inf]
df['MySpecificBins'] = pd.cut(df['MyContinuous'], bins)
```

How can I create my bins in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `np.select` to accomplish your task:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame({'MyContinuous': np.random.randint(1, 70, 10)})

conds = [df['MyContinuous'].between(25, 34),
         df['MyContinuous'].between(19, 24),
         df['MyContinuous'].between(55, 64)]
choices = ['25-34', '19-24', '55-64']

df['MySpecificsBins'] = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices, default='No Interval')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   MyContinuous MySpecificsBins
0            26           25-34
1            56           55-64
2            34           25-34
3             4     No Interval
4            53     No Interval
5            23           19-24
6            18     No Interval
7            54     No Interval
8            48     No Interval
9            40     No Interval
```